# eclipse svn. What version did I have before synchronize with repository

Tags: eclipse, svn

If I do Team -> Synchronise with repository" on a project then I may jump many versions of files if it was a "long time" since last

I am wondering if there is any way to see a log of what version I had before the synchronise.

I suppose I could do Revert to see where I was before but then I would lose my changes. So a log would be better

Note - This is NOT the same as Team -> Show History I think. History is a list of all commits

I need to know what commit I was on before I did Team -> Synchronise with repository"

Peter

Comment: You want the action "Synchronize with repository" itself to print the current revision? Or just a way to show this information before doing the action?

Answer (score 1):

The working copy does not keep track of this information. Once you update from the repository, your WC only reflects that current state. It does not keep track of its own history.

Revert would not do what you're expecting; revert only undoes uncommitted changes in your working copy.

Your only recourse is to run `svn info` **before** `svn update` and make note of the revision you're at, then look at the repository state as of that revision by whatever mechanism you prefer.